# Is there any operator in c which is both unary and binary?

Tags: c, unary-operator, binary-operators

Is there any operator in c which is both unary and binary ? This question was asked in one of the interview.

Comment: Aren't plus (`+`) and minus (`-`) considered binary and unary, depending on where it is?

Comment: @AntonH can you please elaborate on how (+) and (-) are both binary and unary ( other than using ++ or -- i.e increment or decrement ) even I thought in the same way but wanted to know if there are anything specifically.

Comment: `a = a - (-a);` would have the minus sign as binary (operation) and unary (sign).

Comment: actually yes + and - are both unary and binary operators. Also just now I found that &, *  are also binary. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

The asterisk (*) can be used for dereferencing (unary) or multiplication (binary).

The ampersand (&) can be used for referencing (unary) or bitwise AND (binary).

The plus/minus signs (+/-) can be used for identity/negation (unary) or addition/subtraction (binary).

But, as others pointed out, those are symbols shared by different operators. Each of those operators have only one n-arity.

Comment: `*` and `&` are different operators when used as unary and binary.

Comment: @haccks: So are `-` and `+`.

Answer (score 7):

No, there isn't. Every operator is either unary, binary, or ternary.

Some unary and binary operators happen to use the same *symbol*:

- `*` for dereference and multiplication
- `-` for negation and subtraction
- `+` for identity and addition
- `&` for address-of and bitwise "and"

But unary and binary `*` are still distinct operators that happen to be spelled the same way.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>What I think only `.` operator is both unary and binary in C (not specified in standard):</strike>

`.`:-      Unary: In [designators](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) of structures- `{.meber1 = x, .member3 = z}` (C99 and latter). Binary: Accessing structure members.

---

There is no operator in C which is unary and binary as well.
***Symbols***, like `+`, `-`, `*` and `&`, are used as unary and binary operators but then these symbols are treated as *different operators*:

1. `+`, `-` Unary: `i = -1` `j = +1`. Binary: `i = i+1`, `j = j+1`
2. `*`      Unary: Dereference operator. Binary: Multiplication operator.
3. `&`      Unary: Reference operator.   Binary: Bitwise `AND` operator.

Comment: arguably the unary and binary versions of `+` are different operators also

Comment: @MattMcNabb can you please tell what exactly different operators also means?

Comment: @sarigehalli if you look through the list of operators in the C standard, there's a different section for each (unary `+` is in 6.5.3.3, binary `+` is in 6.5.6). Perhaps it is a matter of language, but taking a different number of operands does seem to me to be a difference!

Comment: @haccks: Strictly speaking only in C99/C11 or C89 with GNU extensions applied. However interesting thing is that C99 standard does not list `.` as unary operator. I think it's more like syntactic element, just like `[]` in array declaration.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski; Thanks for nitpicking. I forgot to mention about c99 and also that `.` is not mentioned in ISO C standard.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski; If this question were asked to me in the interview then I had emphasized more on *operator* rather than symbol.

Comment: The `.` symbol in a compound literal is not an operator.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Then what is that?

Comment: @haccks: I am not sure if this is operator or not, just sharing my doubt. Also I found in your answer that `&` should be described as bitwise `AND`, not `OR` (yeah, some minor typo that catched my eye). The question is not strict if this is about operator or operator's symbol.

Comment: @haccks: It's a punctuator, used as part of the syntax of a compound literal (more specifally a *designator*).

Comment: @KeithThompson; Thanks. I was not aware of that.